# How to Solve?? collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status in Debian GCC terminal

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

My File name is hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

and the commands I gave are:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello
$ gcc ./hello
```

The Terminal output is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can please Anyone help me?
I use:

```
gcc version 7.2.0 (Debian 7.2.0-20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello
$ gcc ./hello
```

Assuming you were trying to run it with that second command, it should just be `./hello` (in other words, get rid of the `gcc` at the start).

What you're trying to do is compile/link the *executable* file that you've already compiled from source, when it's already in a state where it can be run.